# How to remove part of column headers in R data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following colnames:

```
R > colnames(crime)

 [1] "http...purl.org.linked.data.sdmx.2009.dimension.refArea"
 [2] "Reference.Area"                                         
 [3] "X1996.1997"                                             
 [4] "X1997.1998"                                             
 [5] "X1998.1999"                                             
 [6] "X1999.2000"                                             
 [7] "X2000.2001"                                             
 [8] "X2001.2002"                                             
 [9] "X2002.2003"                                             
[10] "X2003.2004"                                             
[11] "X2004.2005"                                             
[12] "X2005.2006"                                             
[13] "X2006.2007"                                             
[14] "X2007.2008"                                             
[15] "X2008.2009"                                             
[16] "X2009.2010"                                             
[17] "X2010.2011"                                             
[18] "X2011.2012"                                             
[19] "X2012.2013"                                             
[20] "X2013.2014"                                             
[21] "X2014.2015"                                             
[22] "X2015.2016"                                             
[23] "X2016.2017"                                             
[24] "X2017.2018"
```

and I also have the following column:

```
R > crime[,1]
 [1] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000033
 [2] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000034
 [3] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000041
 [4] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000035
 [5] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000036
 [6] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000005
 [7] http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/S12000006
```

What I would like is for the first column name to be "refArea" and the columns with the years in to be the last 4 numbers, i.e. "X1996.1997" would be "1997". I would also like the first column to just contain the last 9 characters (e.g. S12000006 - the codes are different and some are S02... or S01...)

My current code is as follows:

```
R > colnames(crime)[colnames(crime) == "http...purl.org.linked.data.sdmx.2009.dimension.refArea"] <- "refArea" #replace url with "refArea"

crime$refArea <- substr(crime$refArea, 53, 61) #substring only characters 53-61 from column refArea

colnames(crime) <- c("refArea", "Reference.Area", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018") #Manually change column names
```

But this feels very clunky and poorly coded (and I have to repeat this procedure for 8 or 9 more datasets) - how would you improve on this?

Comment: Try something like `sub(".*\\.(refArea)", "\\1", str1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be `sub` to capture the 'refArea' and remove all the preceding characters.  To remove the "X1996" from 'X1996.1997', we can use `substr`

```
colnames(crime)[1] <- sub(".*\\.(refArea)", "\\1", colnames(crime)[1])
v1 <-  colnames(crime)[3:ncol(crime)] 
colnames(crime)[3:ncol(crime)] <- substr(v1, nchar(v1)-3, nchar(v1))
```

Comment: Thanks - I was able to use the substr for the problem with the individual factors in the column too.

Would it be easier to do this? 

colnames(crime)[1] <- "refArea"

Can you explain what thiese do; ".*\\.(refArea)" / "\\1" ?

Comment: @ScientistStats. Here,  the `refArea` is captured as a group (inside the `()`), while all the other characters preceding `.*` until the `.` is removed.  In the replacement, use the backreference of the captured group